# Installing Oracle Java SE SDK 8u31 via apt-get

Tags: apt, java, ppa

How can I install the Oracle Java SE SDK 8u31 via apt-get on Ubuntu 12.04 (prevcise)?

I tried:

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

from [ppa:webupd8team/java](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java), but it installed 8u45.

After reading [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8_java/precise/main/base/oracle-java8-installer), I tried to run:

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer=8u31+8u33arm-1~webupd8~1
```

but got this error:

```
E: Version '8u31+8u33arm-1~webupd8~0' for 'oracle-java8-installer' was not found
```

How can I downgrade the install from 8u45 to 8u31?  I'm running Grails 2.5.0, which is incompatible with Java SE SDKs newer than 8u31.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to install not latest oracle java from that ppa.

Comment: Thanks.  Are there other PPAs from which I can install 8u31?  Or, is there some other option beside a manual download & install?

Comment: I do not think there are ppa's with old java releases. PPA do not work this way. You can install it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to install the JDK manually if you want to pin the version.  This is a pretty good guide for doing just that.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

Keep in mind no updates, so you'll have to upgrade the java version yourself for security updates and such.